# How to deserealize json date field with jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

Api is returning json having date in format of

```
{
  "modifiedDate": {
    "dayOfWeek": 2,
    "dayOfYear": 172,
    "year": 2022,
    "dayOfMonth": 21,
    "era": 1,
    "monthOfYear": 6,
    "millisOfDay": 12144237,
    "hourOfDay": 3,
    "minuteOfHour": 22,
    "secondOfMinute": 24,
    "millisOfSecond": 237,
    "weekOfWeekyear": 25,
    "weekyear": 2022,
    "yearOfEra": 2022,
    "yearOfCentury": 22,
    "centuryOfEra": 20,
    "secondOfDay": 12144,
    "minuteOfDay": 202,
    "zone": {
      "fixed": true,
      "id": "Etc/UTC"
    },
    "chronology": {
      "zone": {
        "fixed": true,
        "id": "Etc/UTC"
      }
    },
    "millis": 1655781744237,
    "afterNow": false,
    "beforeNow": true,
    "equalNow": false
  }
}
```

How to parse this json into util.Date or Joda DateTime?
We have added CustomDateDeserializer. But challenge is to map this format into object through jackson. Gson is successfully able to parse this.

Comment: I'd say that that API is serializing a date the wrong way. Why would you want to serialize a date in such an unnecessary verbose format? Ask the authors of the API to use a standard format such as ISO-8601.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the default serialization of a `LocalDate` if the proper serializer is not included.

If you can talk to the provider and get them to fix this output (include the `LocalDate` serializer from Jackson) then do that. It make everyone's life easier.

Otherwise, you can just extract the `year`, `monthOfYear` and `dayOfMonth` and create a `LocalDate` from these fields.